# INotifyPropertyChanged, event always null

Tags: c#, handler, inotifypropertychanged

Hi :) I'm trying to figure out how the INotifyPropertyChanged work with a very basic application. I am simply having a button in my mainWindow and when you press it, it should fire of an event to update a textBox, which have been bound to a specific attribute. However, even though the events gets fired of, they are always null and therefore the textBox is not updated.

```
<Window x:Class="StockViewer.MainWindow"
    <!--Just erased some basic xaml here-->
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:RandomGen/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Button Click="incr" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkGoldenrod"></Button>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40" Text="{Binding price, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Aqua"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

When the button is pressed, the price should change:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private RandomGen gen;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        gen = new RandomGen();          
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void incr(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gen.price = 7;
    }
}

class RandomGen : NotifiedImp
    {
     public RandomGen()
        {
            _i = 3;
        }
        private int _i;

        public int price
        {
            get { return _i; }
            set
            {
                _i = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("price");
            }
        }
    }

class NotifiedImp: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }   
        }
    }
```

It's just really strange, the handler is always null. Thank you :)

Comment: You're not binding to `gen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two instances of `RandomGen`, one initialized in your XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
     <local:RandomGen/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And another initialized in your `MainWindow` constructor:

```
gen = new RandomGen();
```

This means when you update `gen.price = 7;` you aren't updating the instance which is your `DataContext`.

One solution would be remove your `<Window.DataContext>` setting in XAML and set `DataContext` in your `MainWindow` constructor, like so:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    gen = new RandomGen();          
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = gen;
}
```

The most MVVM like solution would be to use a `ICommand` on your `RandomGen` object to update `price` rather than using an event handler, then use this command in your XAML, like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding IncrementPriceCommand}"></Button>
```

Then it is up to you how you initialize `DataContext`, you wouldn't need to keep the `RandomGen` backing field either way.